# Coordinate scheduled jobs between multiple producers

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a distributed system of producers and consumers across several servers, with redundant nodes—both for failover and load-balancing. The nodes communicate via RabbitMQ messages.

Each producer runs its own scheduler to invoke jobs, which one of the consumers should run. This works by publishing the appropriate RabbitMQ message, that one of the consumers will process.

Now, the tricky part is, each job should be run only *once*. In short, my requirements are:

- Only *one* invoke message per scheduled job should be processed (by any of the consumer instances)
- If any of the procuders goes down, the job should still be invoked by the other instances

I can't figure out how to implement this without relying on anything else but RabbitMQ. I could make it work if there was such a thing as an "exclusive exchange", which only one producer can connect to at a time. I thought about making the consumers ignore any duplicate invokes for the same job, but this will not work, because due to the load-balancing, subsequent messages may be received by any of the other instances. Another idea was implementing a mechanism to declare one of the producers the "principal" node, so only this one is allowed to send invokes, but this basically presented the same problem of coordinating between instances.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to ensure single run of each job, can we assume that you can identify them clearly? If so, using a string representation of it as primary key in a table should guarantee that it cannot be created more than once. Similarly, locking the row during processing by a consumer, and have it flagged as complete upon processing should allow for single processing too.

Comment: @Olivier You are assuming there is some form of database, which is not indicated in my question.

Comment: I misunderstood your question then, do you mean you can only rely on RabbitMQ and no other component can be used to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: @Olivier Ideally, yes. As I mentioned, if I were to use any additional technology, like a database, this wouldn't pose much of a problem.

Comment: Then you could try with wath would best be described as a crappy hack? Creating a common queue for the producers, and have the producers try to connect to it with the exclusive flag. As only one would be able to do it, it would be the single message publisher, the others retrying to connect on a regular basis to provide failover behavior